# Passing data from MKAnnotationView to UICollectionViewController

Tags: swift, uicollectionview, mkmapview, mkannotation

I have a UICollectionViewController that has a header cell which should display annotations on a map. Each annotation is a business that has information associated to it, and I'd like to display a list of that business's info in the cells below the header (where map is shown)

Right now I can properly load and add annotations to my header cell. But what I'd like to be able to do is actually have the collectionview reload with the appropriate data depending on which annotation a user clicks on in the map header.

Here is the code for my header cell where I load the MKMapView and add necessary methods to add annotations.

```
class MapHeaderCell: UICollectionViewCell, MKMapViewDelegate {

    let mapView: MKMapView = {
        let map = MKMapView()
        map.mapType = .standard
        map.isZoomEnabled = true
        map.isScrollEnabled = true
        return map
    }()

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        backgroundColor = .green

        addSubview(mapView)
        mapView.anchor(top: topAnchor, left: leftAnchor, bottom: bottomAnchor, right: rightAnchor, paddingTop: 0, paddingLeft: 0, paddingBottom: 0, paddingRight: 0, width: 0, height: 0)

        guard let latitude = UserDefaultConstants().latitude, let longitude = UserDefaultConstants().longitude  else {
            return
        }

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude, longitude: longitude)
        let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: coordinate, span:  MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
        mapView.setRegion(region, animated: false)
    }

    func addAnnotations(businesses: [Business]) {
        for business in businesses {
            let annotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            annotation.title = business.name
            annotation.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: business.latitude, longitude: business.longitude)
            mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
        }
    }

    //adds annotation to view.
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, viewFor annotation: MKAnnotation) -> MKAnnotationView? {
        guard annotation is MKPointAnnotation else { return nil }
        var annotationView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationView(withIdentifier: annotationId)

        if annotationView == nil {
            annotationView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: annotationId)
            annotationView!.canShowCallout = true
        } else {
            annotationView!.annotation = annotation
        }
        return annotationView
    }
}
```

In another class I actually load the local business's data, and then populate the map.

```
class MapCollectionVewController: ListCollectionViewControllerBase {

var coupons = [Coupon]()
var businesses = [Business]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(CouponCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: listCellId)
    collectionView?.register(MapHeaderCell.self, forSupplementaryViewOfKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: mapHeaderId)

    getLocalBusinesses()
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, referenceSizeForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGSize { 
    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 200)

}

//THIS IS WHERE I ADD ANNOTATIONS TO MAP
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: mapHeaderId, for: indexPath) as! MapHeaderCell
    header.addAnnotations(businesses: businesses)
    return header
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return coupons.count
}

override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: listCellId, for: indexPath) as! CouponCell
    cell.coupon = coupons[indexPath.item]
    cell.hideFavoritesButton()
    return cell
}

fileprivate func getLocalBusinesses() {
    guard let latitude = UserDefaultConstants().latitude, let longitude = UserDefaultConstants().longitude else {
        print("No latitude/longitude value stored for user")
        return
    }

    let url = ConfigKeys.apiBaseURI + "business/nearby"
    let params = ["latitude": latitude, "longitude": longitude]

    let apiController = APIController(email: UserDefaultConstants().userEmail, token: UserDefaultConstants().userToken)
    apiController.makeRequest(type: .get, url: url, parameters: params) { (success, error, data) in
        if !success {
            print("error with request: ", error ?? "in getLocalBusiness")
        }

        guard let data = data else {return}
        guard let resultsArray = data["result"] as? [[String : Any]] else {return}

        for result in resultsArray {
            let business = Business(data: result)
            self.businesses.append(business)
        }

        self.collectionView?.reloadData()
    }
}
}
```

So to re-iterate: I need to be able to load up business data in the collection view below the mapview based on which annotation a user clicks on. I've read some solutions here that have guaded me, but Have been unable to work this out.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution I needed. Posting in case someone requires this as well. Somewhat lengthy but this should do trick in most cases.

Create this protocol:

```
protocol MapHeaderCellDelgate {
    func didSelectBusiness(id: Int)
}
```

In MapHeaderCell create a variable which is the delegate. In the DidSelect delegate method for MKMapViewDelegate just pass the data which you need in whatever view controller.

```
var delegate: MapHeaderCellDelgate?

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {

        if let annotation = view.annotation as? BusinessAnnotation {
            print("Your annotation title: \(annotation.businessId)");
            guard let businessId = annotation.businessId else {return}
            delegate?.didSelectBusiness(id: businessId)
        }
    }
```

In my View Controller I first conform the collectionview to the protocol (MapHeaderCellDelegate) created

```
class MapCollectionVewController: ListCollectionViewControllerBase, MapHeaderCellDelgate
```

in the viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind method be sure to set the header cells delegate to self

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind kind: String, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionReusableView {

    let header = collectionView.dequeueReusableSupplementaryView(ofKind: UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader, withReuseIdentifier: mapHeaderId, for: indexPath) as! MapHeaderCell

    header.delegate = self
    header.addAnnotations(businesses: businesses)
    return header
}
```

And finally in the protocol method you can now use the data you just passed to do whatever you want with it. Be sure to reload collectionView once done with data so that the view updates with anything you need displayed

```
func didSelectBusiness(id: Int) {
    someFunction(id: id)
}

func someFunction(id: Int) {
    //DO STUFF
    //...
    collectionView?.reloadData()
}
```